# Python Profiling problems, about exec_dynamic

Tags: python, performance, profiling

I'm profiling my code recently and I get stuck because there's
a build in functions cost most of times in my code.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ne2tG.png)

What does {built-in method _imp.exec_dynamic} actually do
and what can I do for the better performance?

I google it but I can't find too much information on the internet,
Is this problem relating to the dot operator, like np.pi or something else?

Can somebody give me advises or is there a way for studying this function?  Thanks!

Comment: You might consider using a better profiler like [Scalene](https://github.com/plasma-umass/scalene) which provides more granular information along with tons of other info. Full disclosure, I am one of the authors of Scalene.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion.  I wonder if there has a window platform solution since my computer os is window. But I'll try it if I could!

Comment: You see how the profiler is leading you down the garden path? Even good ones miss the problem. You should be aware of [*this method*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/378024/23771).

Comment: I have solved this problems, I found that the trace is broken since I'm using cython .pyx in my packages and my profiler can't trace it directly therefore I should need to use cython profiling technique instead.